# Python with Vector CANoe

Tags: python, can-bus, capl, canoe

I try to send a message via python to Vector CANoe. First I have configured CAPL node to send a cyclic message and it works (id 0x100). Then I would like to send a message via python - my code is below, but i get "Not Acknowledge error, dominant error flag" [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwhOq.png). Do You know what might be a problem? I have configured "TX-Self-ACK" in Network Hardware Configuration otherwise even sending message via CAPL module didn't work.

```
import can
import time
from can.interfaces.vector import canlib
from datetime import datetime


bus = canlib.VectorBus(channel=0, can_filters=None, poll_interval=0.01, 
receive_own_messages=False, bitrate=500000, rx_queue_size=16384, 
app_name='CANoe', serial=None, fd=False, data_bitrate=None, 
jw_abr=2, tseg1_abr=6, tseg2_abr=3, sjw_dbr=2, tseg1_dbr=6, tseg2_dbr=3)

messageSend = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x200, data=b'\x07\x31\x01\x60\x60\x01\x00\x01',channel=0, 
is_fd=False, check=True)

bus.send(messageSend, timeout=0.1)
print(messageSend)
received_message = bus.recv()
received_message.timestamp
print(f'Received: {datetime.fromtimestamp(received_message.timestamp)}')`
```